# How to do CRUD connecting multiple collection table MONGODB MEANSTACK

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

I wish to know how to create a connection between the `MongoDB` collection. For example, I have a workspace and company collection.
Scenario -> workspace.id ="aaa" company={ id:"asd" workspaceId:"aaa"} (related back to workspace "aaa" as you see I mentioned in company collection).

```
const Company = module.exports = function Company(aux) {this.id; this._name;}

const Workspace = module.exports = function Workspace( aux ){this.id;
this._name;}
```

Therefore I could just delete the workspace "aaa" and all the company which under workspaceId = "aaa" would be deleted as well.
Help would be appreciated a lot.